# MPI convert matrix to upper triangular form in C++ doesn't work

Tags: c++, matrix, mpi

I'm new to MPI; so forgive me if my code is clumsy. I want to convert a n*n matrix to upper triangular form and then calculate its determinant. My code works with one processor, but with more than one processor, it doesn't work.  I am hoping someone can give me some advice about it.
My code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>  /* For strlen             */
#include <mpi.h>     /* For MPI functions, etc */
#include<stdlib.h>    /* for rand */
#include<math.h>
#define n 10
#define N 100

int main(void)
{
    srand(0);
    double A[N];
    double temp[N];
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int m=100;
    int s=1;
    int y;
    double z;
    double det=1;
    int pid;
    int np;
    int share=0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    { 
        A[i] = rand();
    }
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pid);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &np);
    if (np == 1)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (A[i * n + i] == 0)
            {
                s = 0;
                for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if (A[j * n + i] != 0)
                    {
                        for (k = i; k < n; k++)
                        {
                            A[i * n + k] = A[i * n + k] + A[j * n + k];
                        }
                        s = 1;
                    }
                    if (s == 1)
                        break;
                }
            }
            if (s != 1)
            {
                det = 0;
                break;
            }
            z = A[i * n + i];
            det = det * z;
            for (k = i; k < n; k++)
            {
                A[i * n + k] = A[i * n + k] / z;
            }
            for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                z = A[j * n + i];
                for (k = i; k < n; k++)
                {
                    A[j * n + k] = A[j * n + k] - z * A[i * n + k];
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            printf("element %d of matrix is %G  \n", i, A[i]);
        }
        printf("det is %G", det);
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < n ; i++)
        {
            if (A[i * n + i] == 0)
            {
                s = 0;
                for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if (A[j * n + i] != 0)
                    {
                        for (k = i; k < n; k++)
                        {
                            A[i * n + k] = A[i * n + k] + A[j * n + k];
                        }
                        s = 1;
                    }
                    if (s == 1)
                        break;
                }
            }
            if (s != 1)
            {
                det = 0;
                break;
            }
            z = A[i * n + i];
            det = det * z;
            for (k = i; k < n; k++)
            {
                A[i * n + k] = A[i * n + k] / z;
            }
            m = n - i;
            if (m > 1)
            {
                if (np >= m)
                {
                    if (pid == 0)
                    {
                        for (k = 1; k < m; k++)
                        {
                            MPI_Send(&m, 1, MPI_INT, k, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                            MPI_Send(&A[(k + i) * n + i], m, MPI_DOUBLE, k, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                        }
                        for (k = 1; k < m; k++)
                        {
                            MPI_Recv(&temp[0], m + 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
                            for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
                            {
                                A[(int(temp[m]) + i) * n + i + j] = temp[j];
                            }
                        }
                        printf("det is %G", det);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        double local_A[N];
                        double local_z;
                        int local_m;
                        MPI_Recv(&local_m, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
                        MPI_Recv(&local_A[0], local_m, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
                        local_z = local_A[0];
                        for (k = 0; k < m; k++)
                        {
                            local_A[k] = local_A[k] - (local_z * A[(i * n) + i + k]);
                        }
                        local_A[k + 1] = pid;
                        MPI_Send(&local_A[0], local_m + 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                    }
                }
                if (np < m)
                {
                    if (m % np == 0)
                    {
                        if (pid == 0)
                        {
                            share = m / np;
                            for (k = 1; k < np; k++)
                            {
                                MPI_Send(&m, 1, MPI_INT, k, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                                MPI_Send(&share, 1, MPI_INT, k, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                                MPI_Send(&A[share * k * n], share * n, MPI_DOUBLE, k, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                            }
                            for (k = 1; k < share; k++)
                            {
                                z = A[(k + i) * n + i];
                                for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
                                {
                                    A[(k + i) * n + i + j] = A[(k + i) * n + i + j] - z;
                                }
                            }
                            for (k = 1; k < np; k++)
                            {
                                MPI_Recv(&temp[0], share * m + 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
                                for (j = 0; j < share * m; j++)
                                {
                                    A[(int(temp[share * m]) + i) * n * share + i + j] = temp[j];
                                }
                            }
                            printf("det is %G", det);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            double local_A[N];
                            double local_z;
                            int local_share;
                            int local_m;
                            MPI_Recv(&local_m, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
                            MPI_Recv(&local_share, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
                            MPI_Recv(&local_A[0], local_share * n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
                            for (k = 0; k < local_share; k++)
                            {
                                local_z = local_A[(k + i) * n + i];
                                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                                {
                                    local_A[k * n + j] = local_A[(k + i) * n + i + j] - local_z;
                                }
                            }
                            local_A[local_share * local_m] = pid;
                            MPI_Send(&local_A[0], share * local_m + 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                        }
                    }
                    if (m % np != 0)
                    {
                        if (pid == 0)
                        {
                            share = m / np;
                            for (k = 1; k < np; k++)
                            {
                                MPI_Send(&m, 1, MPI_INT, k, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                                MPI_Send(&share, 1, MPI_INT, k, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                                MPI_Send(&A[share * k * n], share * n, MPI_DOUBLE, k, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                            }
                            for (k = 1; k < share; k++)
                            {
                                z = A[(k + i) * n + i];
                                for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
                                {
                                    A[(k + i) * n + i + j] = A[(k + i) * n + i + j] - z;
                                }
                            }
                            for (k = 1; k < np; k++)
                            {
                                MPI_Recv(&temp[0], share * m + 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
                                for (j = 0; j < share * m; j++)
                                {
                                    A[(int(temp[share * m]) + i) * n * share + i + j] = temp[j];
                                }
                            }
                            for (k = 1; k < (m % np) + 1; k++)
                            {
                                y = (share * np) + k;
                                MPI_Send(&y, 1, MPI_INT, k, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                                MPI_Send(&A[(share * np + i + k) * n + i], m, MPI_DOUBLE, k, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                            }
                            for (k = 1; k < m; k++)
                            {
                                MPI_Recv(&temp[0], m + 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
                                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                                {
                                    A[int(temp[n]) * n + i + j] = temp[j];
                                }
                            }
                            printf("det is %G", det);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            double local_A[N];
                            double local_z;
                            double local_y;
                            int local_share;
                            int local_m;
                            MPI_Recv(&local_m, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
                            MPI_Recv(&local_share, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
                            MPI_Recv(&local_A[0], local_share * n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
                            for (k = 0; k < local_share; k++)
                            {
                                local_z = local_A[(k + i) * n + i];
                                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                                {
                                    local_A[k * n + j] = local_A[(k + i) * n + i + j] - local_z;
                                }
                            }
                            local_A[local_share * local_m] = pid;
                            MPI_Send(&local_A[0], local_share * local_m + 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                            MPI_Recv(&local_y, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
                            MPI_Recv(&local_A[0], m, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
                            local_z = local_A[0];
                            for (j = 0; j < local_m; j++)
                            {
                                local_A[j] = local_A[j] - local_z;
                            }
                            local_A[j + 1] = local_y;
                            MPI_Send(&local_A[0], m + 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Even with two or treee processor my code doesn't work, and I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried running this with 2 processes. On line 225, you are reading out of bounds of the array `A` with `N=100 n=10 np=2 i=1 j=19 k=1 m=9 share=4 temp[share*m]=1`. If you are using GCC, you can catch this by using the address sanitizer (the command line argument `-fsanitize=address` when compiling). I don't understand the math well enough to find out where the numbers come from.

Comment: Just a word of advice, posting a large block of code and asking why it doesn't work suggests that you have not put very much effort into debugging. Best of luck debugging this!